# JUpload combine with codeigniter

Tags: java, codeigniter, applet, jupload

does anyone tried JUpload java applet with codeigniter?

this is my views

```
<h1 align="center">JUpload PHP Sample Page</h1>
<div align="center">
<APPLET
    CODE="wjhk.jupload2.JUploadApplet"
    NAME="JUpload"
    ARCHIVE="../../../../jar/wjhk.jupload.jar"
    WIDTH="640"
    HEIGHT="300"
    MAYSCRIPT="true"
    ALT="The java pugin must be installed.">
    <param name="postURL" value="ftp://username:password@host:21/testupload" />
    <param name="ftpCreateDirectoryStructure" value="true" />
    <param name="showLogWindow" value="onError">
    <param name="afterUploadURL" value="javascript:alert('Upload done');">
    <param name="debugLevel" value="99">
    <param name="showStatusBar" value="True">
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="25000000">
    <param name="maxChunkSize" value="25000000">
    <param name="httpUploadParameterType" value="iteration">
    <param name="nbFilesPerRequest" value="100">
    <param name="stringUploadSuccess" value="SUCCESS">
    <param name="stringUploadWarning" value="WARNING">
    <param name="stringUploadError" value="ERROR">

    Java 1.5 or higher plugin required. 

</APPLET>
</div>
```

but I have no luck to post my ftp, the error says:

> java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException in JUploadPanelImpl.doStartUpload()

before I try with codeigniter, I try with pure PHP and it worked. Please help me how to combine this JUpload with codeigniter

Thank you

Comment: Why exactly are you using JUpload instead of the already present upload functionality in CodeIgniter? =)

Comment: @Crowlix, yes I know. But cannot read on local directory

Comment: this might be an obvious question, but have you tested your connection string? ("ftp://username:password...") SecurityException occur when you don't get access and invalid credentials are the most common mistakes

Comment: @Crowlix sorry being late for reply, yes I already tested the connection and everything is fine. If I read my error alert mean is I have like I do same execution in one time, but I don't know it is true or not..

Comment: My guess would be that your server just doesn't allow remote access to ftp, which server are you using?

Comment: @Crowlix thanks with all your suggest, now everything it's works. This is because I don't know the JUpload error means, so I make some mistakes in my PHP code.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check for bad credentials (username,password).

If that's not the cause then my guess would be that your server doesn't allow remote access to ftp.
Configure your server for proper access.